# Using $_GET in Functions.php

Tags: php

I keep getting an undefined index error with this code in functions. What am I doing wrong?

```
function hire_more(){

    $hire = $_GET['hire_more'];

    write_log($hire);

}

add_action('wp_loaded','hire_more');
```

Comment: The proper way is to check if that argument is set first: `$hire = isset($_GET['hire_more']) ? $_GET['hire_more'] : null;` or `if ( isset($_GET['hire_more'])  ) add_action('wp_loaded','hire_more');`

Answer (score 2):

Not really a WordPress related question, but the answer is fairly simple. When you try to call an element of a array that doesn't exist, you will get an undefined index error, since it simply doesn't exist.

`$_GET` is a superglobal array, so this is the case. To fix this issue, you should first check and see if that particular element is set.

For example:

```
function hire_more() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['hire_more'] ) ) {
        $hire = $_GET['hire_more'];
        write_log($hire);
    }

}
add_action('wp_loaded','hire_more');
```

Comment: Ok thats good to know, but I'm still getting no value when I use /?hire_more=1

Comment: `write_log` isn't a WordPress or PHP function. Have you defined it anywhere?

Comment: @MiguelDey Instead, use `error_log( $hire );` and check your PHP log for the variable dump.